# Spring jdbc:embedded-database not able to access jdbc driver on JBoss AS 7

Tags: spring, hsqldb, jboss7.x

I'm using Spring's `<jdbc:embedded>` to run integration and acceptance tests using HSQLDB. If I include the `hsqldb.jar` on the application's classpath then everything works but moving the driver to JBoss as a module I get the following exception:

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: 
Property 'databaseType' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Driver for test database type [HSQL] is not available in the classpath
```

JBoss can see the driver as I can configure a datatsource on JBoss using the it but can't figure out why it's not on my application classpath. Are jdbc drivers only available through a configured datasource on Jboss or is there something else i need to do to make it available?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe answer in not relative already, but anyway.
You should add `hsqldb.jar` to classpath
If using maven check latest version from [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb), and add to pom.
Or find latest on [official website](http://hsqldb.org/) and use it.
All best!

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in using Spring's  but with H2 database. There are 2 possibilities, you can put the corresponding .jar to your database in the lib folder of your server. Or you can put it in your webApp. i have chosen the latest possibility, so i put this dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <version>XXXXXX</version>
```

Comment: h2 library has nothing to do with HSQL

Comment: i believe @gibers was implying to just use H2 instead of hSQL...which worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just add dependency on HSQL library. If you are using maven, then:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```